# Download PDF from PeerJ

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I am trying to use Python `requests` to download a PDF from [PeerJ](https://peerj.com). For example, https://peerj.com/articles/1.pdf.

My code is simply:

```
r = requests.get('https://peerj.com/articles/1.pdf')
```

However, the `Response` object returned displays as `<Response [432]>`, which indicates an HTTP 432 error. As far as I know, that error code is not assigned.

When I examine `r.text` or `r.content`, there is some HTML which says that it's an error 432 and gives a link to the same PDF, https://peerj.com/articles/1.pdf.

I can view the PDF when I open it in my browser (Chrome).

How do I get the actual PDF (as a `bytes` object, like I should get from `r.content`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While opening the site, you have mentioned, I also opened the developer tool in my firefox browser and copied the http request header from there and assigned it to headers parameter in request.get funcion.

`a = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,/;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 'peerj.com',
'Referer': 'https://peerj.com/articles/1.pdf',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0'}`

r = requests.get('https://peerj.com/articles/1.pdf', headers= a)

Comment: would even work with <code>a = {
'Referer': 'https://peerj.com/articles/1.pdf'}

r = requests.get('https://peerj.com/articles/1.pdf', headers= a)</code>